# Can I setup XCode 5.1.1 to run iPad2 simulators?

Tags: xcode5

I tried downloading old Xcode, but
Things I've tried

1. Downloading XCode 4.3.3, but it won't run on 10.9.1
2. copying XCode 4.3.3 folders into XCode 5.1.1:

   - iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
   - iPhoneOS5.1.sdk

Answer (score 0):

Technically Xcode 5.1.1 does emulate the iPad 2 - just select "iPad" (without Retina or 64 bit) from the drop down:

[image]

Reading between the lines, it looks like you're trying to emulate iOS 5 rather than iPad 2 specifically (which runs iOS 7.x just fine). If that's the case, please note that Mavericks no longer supports the iOS 5 simulator due to Kernel changes. You must run Xcode 5.0 under Mountain Lion for the iOS 5 simulator to work.

This article has further details - perhaps it will help: 
http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-build-apps-for-ios-5-with-xcode-5/